# An Inequality about the Average of Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed $N(m,\sigma^2)$ random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, F,P)$, where $\sigma>0$. Fix $0<\epsilon<|a|$. Prove that the following equation holds for sufficiently large $n$:

\begin{equation}
P\left\{\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - (m+a)\right|<\sigma \epsilon\right\} \geqslant \sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon^2n}{\pi}} \exp\left[-\frac{n(\epsilon+|a|)^2}{2}\right]
\end{equation}

My attempt:

Since $X_1$ is $N(m, \sigma^2)$, we automatically have the shifted average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-m$ to be $N(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. Therefore:

\begin{equation*}
P\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-m| \geqslant \sigma \epsilon\} = \frac{1}{\sigma} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}(\int_{\sigma \epsilon}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{y^2n}{2\sigma^2}}dy+ \int_{-\infty}^{-\sigma \epsilon}e^{-\frac{y^2n}{2\sigma^2}}dy) = \frac{2}{\sigma} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{\epsilon \sqrt{n}}{2}}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}dy
\end{equation*}

Markov's inequality then shows that the following inequality holds for every positive integer $n$:

\begin{equation}
P\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-m| \geqslant \sigma \epsilon\} \leqslant \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n\epsilon^2}{2}}
\end{equation}

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary in the above inequality, I can replace it by $\epsilon \pm \frac{a}{\sigma}$ to obtain the following two inequalities:

\begin{equation*}
P\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-m| \geqslant a+\sigma \epsilon\} \leqslant \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n(\epsilon+\frac{a}{\sigma})^2}{2}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
P\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-m| \geqslant a-\sigma \epsilon\} \leqslant \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n(\epsilon-\frac{a}{\sigma})^2}{2}}
\end{equation*}

Combine them:

\begin{equation*}
P(\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-m| \geqslant a+\sigma \epsilon\}\cup \{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-m| \geqslant a-\sigma \epsilon\}) \leqslant \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n(\epsilon+\frac{a}{\sigma})^2}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n(\epsilon-\frac{a}{\sigma})^2}{2}}
\end{equation*}

Take complement:

\begin{equation*}
P\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-(m+a)|<\sigma \epsilon\} \geqslant 1- \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n(\epsilon+\frac{a}{\sigma})^2}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-\frac{n(\epsilon-\frac{a}{\sigma})^2}{2}}
\end{equation*}

I feel like I am very close to success but I am stuck here. How do I get the required form in the inequality ?

Comment: Unless I am missing something (again) - $e^{-n}$ decreases very fast, you want to prove that the probability is bigger than something small and you showed it is bigger than $1 - small - small$. So, all you have to do is to show that $3*small <= 1$

Comment: Pls check $\sigma \downarrow 0$, the right side doesn't depend on $\sigma$.